# How to decode float32 tif images to float32 tensor in tensoflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a sets of input images (rgb) and image targets (grayscale) in float32 data type by tif format. Is it possible to decode them into float32 tensor in tensorflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing this comment `tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff()`. Nevertheless the output format is uint8 rather than float32.

I suggest that you read the image with OpenCV or Pillow.

E.g with OpenCV:

```
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
image = cv2.imread('image.tif')
tf_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image, dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Timbus Calin thanks for your reply. does "tf.convert_to_tensor" also support a list of images as input?